# Unzip files in Linux using bash cause errors when path contains spaces

Tags: linux, bash, unzip

File path like this:
path/path/path/File name 2.3.pdf.zip

What am I doing wrong:

```
# unzip files back to normal
# and remove zip files
for f in `find "$1" -type f -iname "*.zip"`; do
        dir=`dirname "$f"`
        unzip -o "$f" -d "$dir"
        rm -f "$f"
done
```

Error message:
unzip:  cannot find or open file, file.zip, or file.ZIP

Using UnZip 5.52
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)

Comment: unzip -o "$f" -d "$dir"   "$f" ; also from man unzip :   -o     overwrite existing files without prompting.  This is a dangerous option, so use it with care.  (It is often used with -f, however, and is the only  way  to
              overwrite directory EAs under OS/2.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your loop is splitting up the output of `find` based on the spaces. You may want to do something to read one line at a time, like this

```
find "$1" -type f -iname "*.zip" | while read f
do
    dir=`dirname "$f"`
    unzip -o "$f" -d "$dir"
    rm -f "$f"
done
```

Or, alternatively, you could set IFS:

```
IFS='\n'
for f in `find "$1" -type f -iname "*.zip"`; do
        dir=`dirname "$f"`
        unzip -o "$f" -d "$dir"
        rm -f "$f"
done
```

Comment: the first option did it. I think this is what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is here

```
dir=`dirname $f`
```

Try instead

```
dir=`dirname "$f"`
```

Also, you have some unnecessary semicolons at the end of a few of your lines.

Comment: I made those changes, but same issue

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your post to include the error message(s).